# Powershell - Publish Designer workflow on all sites

Tags: 2013, workflow, powershell, reusable

As a follow up to my previous question on editing a workflow;

[Activating a Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Feature](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153018/activating-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow-feature)

I have been able to change the contents of the workflow and publish it, however the problem is the change is made to only one site. Ideally I would publish the site to all pages at once via the root but this does not happen. I have tried using the script found below;

http://www.sharepointappie.nl/deploying-spd-workflows-with-powershell/

But this script does not find our custom workflow - only the built ins. The workflow works and is activated so I'm pretty stumped as to why I can't find it.

The custom workflow is a 2013 reusable workflow created in SharePoint Designer.

Any ideas on how I can mass publish the workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I eventually found the solution to this.

The workflow is based upon a Visual Studio solution created by another company. Within that is the code to run/deploy the SP Designer workflow and most importantly an XAML file.

I followed the steps in this link to get a copy of the WSP file that contains the workflow;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj819316.aspx

I saved the .WSP with the .CAB extension to view the contents of the folder.

After this had been done, I replaced the XAML file in Visual Studio and published the solution. This removed the old copy of the workflow on all sites and replaced it with my new version.

One caveat is the company did create deployment scripts which made this as simple as clicking publish - this may not be the case for everyone but did resolve my issue.